# Safely resize partitions Debian?

Tags: debian, partition

A week ago I had Windows 7 only. Then I installed Debian Jessie 8.2. I made mistakes (I think) on the partitions sizes, I thought it was a good idea to do something like this (and I did it):

-/    300 GB
-/home 40 GB
-swap 7 GB

Now that I've started to understand Linux better, and Debian in particular, it seems that I got swap partition right (I have around 3GB of RAM, and it's recommended to set around 1.5 or 2 times that on swap, I put a little more, but I think that can't hurt) , but I've should created a home partition of 300 GB and a / partition of 40 GB, because all the programs and user data are stored in home (This is probably false, I'm very new in linux, I didn't installed almost any program except for a couple of packages).

I'm getting very confused because inside root there is a folder called home. But in the installation process I partitioned in the 3 separate partitions as stated above. It doesn't make sense to me that one partition is inside another one. For you to understand better my disk, here is a command line session:

```
qwerty@aral:~$ su
Password: 
root@aral:/home/qwerty# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 596.2 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7f68575b

Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     206847    204800  100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2           206848  482551807 482344960  230G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        482553854 1204074495 721520642  344G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       1204074496 1250258943  46184448   22G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda5        482553856 1107553855 625000000  298G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1107554304 1121226751  13672448  6.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       1121228800 1204074495  82845696 39.5G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

So if you can clear this last doubt it would be helpful, and also if you can tell me if this is a good partitioning scheme for a 2 user home desktop computer.

If it's not, I'm going to make another question on how to partition without loosing my data, but if you want to give a hint on what the next step or question should be it's welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

To move or resize disk partitions, an easy way is to use GParted. It's a gnome tool, but it can be used on live USB and it's pretty safe.

http://gparted.org

After downloaded and wrote it on USB key, you just need boot on it, the rest is quite intuitive (you will see all your disk and differents partitions, and click on it to resize or move it, see below).

[image]

If you want to move a bootable partition, I recommand you to backup it before.

Comment: My post had two questions inside and neither were answered here. What about my partition scheme, is it good? Why do i have one partition inside another?

Comment: @Santropedro I recomand you to read http://superuser.com/questions/783037/making-sense-of-partition-tables, it should awnser to theses questions.

Comment: that post had 4 questions, neither of them had nothing to do with my 2 particular concerns. What lines in particular of that post answer my questions?

Comment: @Santropedro I think you haven't home partition include in root one, it's home  partition `/home` mounted on root one `/` (I don't know if it's awnser you're looking for). If installed with apt-get, binaries by default are not going into your home directory, you can see where files go with `dpkg -L <packagename>` command.