# Low size on home directory

Tags: partition, swap, gparted

Well I created a directory in the home directory in order to copy some books from my hard drive, and I found that there wasn't enough space on the home directory.

As you can see below, I have got 377G (available) mounted on the root directory[dev/sda5], but only 38G mounted on the home directory of which only 16G is available [dev/sda7].

**How do I get all that big space in the root into my home directory, so that I can utilize the space!?**

```
 $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           339M  1.8M  337M   1% /run
/dev/sda5       413G   16G  377G   5% /
tmpfs           1.7G   59M  1.6G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop2       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop1       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
/dev/loop3      161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop4      162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop5      256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
/dev/loop6      256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop8       63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop7       44M   44M     0 100% /snap/riseup-vpn/159
/dev/loop9       44M   44M     0 100% /snap/riseup-vpn/161
/dev/loop10      31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/7777
/dev/loop11      30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8140
/dev/loop12     2.8M  2.8M     0 100% /snap/telegram-cli/25
/dev/loop13     124M  124M     0 100% /snap/tusk/29
/dev/loop15      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/youtube-dl/2846
/dev/loop14      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/youtube-dl/2840
/dev/sda1       256M   54M  203M  21% /boot/efi
/dev/sda7        38G   21G   16G  57% /home
tmpfs           339M   72K  339M   1% /run/user/1000
```

[image: The partition layout on gparted]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely resize partitions Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248781/safely-resize-partitions-debian)

Comment: But how do I do it exactly on gparted? The sda6 is between sda5 and sda7.

Comment: This is true, but it is a _swap_ partition and doesn't contain any critical data. You will be doing this using a live USB stick anyway, so you can just delete sda6, perform the necessary moving/resizing on `/` and `/home`, and create a new swap partition later. Just be sure to edit the `/etc/fstab` to reflect possible changes in the partition numbering (if it is not UUID-based anyway).

Comment: I see. I understand. So I first need to make changes to the /etc/fstab file, and then by using a live USB, delete the /dev/sda6 partition, resize / and /home, and then create a new swap partition. Is it right?

Comment: If it is right, then how do I go about changing the /etc/fstab file? Kindly help.

Comment: I see. First, backup, and then resizing using gparted, and then editing the /etc/fstab file. But what changes should I precisely make to the fstab file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should resize your partitions, reducing the space assigned to `/dev/sda5` and increasing that for `/dev/sda7`. This is the best long-term strategy.

Obviously this is awkward and does not consider what might happen to `/dev/sda6`.

---

## update: /dev/sda6 is swap.

Since `/dev/sda6` is a swap partition, then you can safely perform the following. Note: almost the same applies if you can temporarily backup `sda6` somewhere (possibly on a file in the root filesystem using `dd`).

- disable the swap in `/etc/fstab`.
- use `swapoff` to unload the swap, or backup `sda6` if it is not swap.
- *(recommended)* reboot to single user mode.
- use `resize2fs` to shrink the `/` file system (but not the partition)
- resize the root partition to match the smaller file system
- remove the useless `/dev/sda6` from the partition table.
- create a new `sda6` partition from the free space plus the space left by the old `sda6`
- format the resulting `sda6` and rsync `/home` to it.
- get the UUID of the new sda6 partition with `blkid`, mount it as /home in fstab.
- unmount the old home in /dev/sda7. **Verify that the new /home mounts OK**. Now `/dev/sda7` has become redundant.
- remove `/dev/sda7`.
- [increase the size of /dev/sda6](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-resize-ext4-root-partition-live-without-umount) into the newly created free space, leaving enough space for swap
- recreate a smaller `/dev/sda7` for swap from that reduced space.
- resize the file system in sda6 with resize2fs to match the larger partition size.
- `mkswap` `/dev/sda7` and set it using its UUID in fstab; activate it with `swapon` (or restore from backup)
- *(recommended)* reboot and run `fsck` to ensure everything is copacetic.

You now have a larger /home in `/dev/sda6` and a swap in `/dev/sda7`. Everything else remains unchanged. With care, you might even not need to reboot, though I recommend it to catch any mistakes you might have done (e.g. wrong UUID in fstab, etc.).

Errors in partition/filesystem size matching may result in **total data loss**, so unless you're very sure of yourself, **a full backup is also strongly recommended**.

---

Some partition editors could allow you to *split* `/dev/sda5` and create a further partition inside. You would have unordered partitions: 5, 8, 6 and 7. Format partition 8, rsync home onto partition 8, mount home there, and now you have a home of, say, 200 GB, and a free /dev/sda7 which you can merge with /dev/sda6 (remember to enlarge the filesystem afterwards).

Another possibility is to create an area in `/dev/sda5` which is writable by your user, say `/opt/books`. Being on `/dev/sda5`, this area has 377 GB of free space. Create a symlink in home (books -> /opt/books) and you will *seem* to have 377 GB of books in your home, while they actually aren't. Quick and dirty, but it might work for you.

Note that several backup strategies (e.g. "time machine" rsync + hardlink based) assume that /home is **all on a single file system**, through flags like `rsync`'s `-x` or the explicit use of hard links. These strategies will now either fail or silently omit to backup the content of what *looks like* the `/home/user/books` directory. That backup may or may not be added to the backup for / (but /opt is often omitted and offloaded to a different backup. On one system I for example have separate backups for `/etc`, `/opt` and `/usr/local`, with / otherwise not backed up at all - being a standard distro, given the config and the list of packages I just reinstall it from scratch).

Other fancier methods exist.

Comment: I would certainly go with the option of making a new hierarchy within /. That avoids any tinkering with partitioning, and is much more flexible. You can use this as a quasi-public area, with detailed control on individual user directories. So it is good for shared projects, or communal needs like databases or research materials. You may need to rethink your backup strategy.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant all very good points. I'm adding to my answer.

Comment: That's a good idea too.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have LVM so a pig way to do is to make a directory on / partition linked to a subdirectory behind /home ...

A better way to do that is to use advanced partition tools like gparted or so ... to try to shrink sda5 & give size to sda7 or at least make a sda8 mounted as a subdirectory of /home  (all of that from a live-cd)

if you have absolutly not data or a backup of it all & if you can reinstall with LVM & more intelligent partitionning it is really better ....

for **example** LVM activated

```
/     2g
/boot 1g
/usr  16g
/var  8g
/home 200g
```